# How would I write a regular expression which matches

Tags: regex

Given the following data

1. `"apple orange plum"`
2. `"apple grape plum"`

I will have a given term which will determine if something is a match.

e.g "apple orange plum pear cherry"

I need to write a regular expression which will match on [1.] but not [2.] because my term does not contain "grape"

I dont know if this is possible or not with regular expressions?

Comment: It's possible.  What flavor regex are you using?  What have you tried?

Comment: I have been playing with lots of variations on http://www.regexr.com/ which I have spent hours googling for, I havent been able to edit those to something which matches.

Comment: short answer: yes It is possible with regular expressions

Comment: expected answer: [demo regex](https://regex101.com/r/zO2aY8/2)

Comment: Hi Jose, that might just do it, expect the [1.], [2.] were added just for clarification, it was not part of the data

Comment: @Matthew then is more simple [demo regex](https://regex101.com/r/zO2aY8/3)

Comment: @Matthew I improved RE add "non capture group" .... because words like to "appleplum"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
^(((apple|orange|plum|pear|chery)(?: |$))+)$
```

[**DEMO regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/zO2aY8/5)

**Explanation**

`(apple|orange|plum|pear|chery)` any of these words

`(?: |$)` [non capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group)

Answer (score 1):

Languages that support lookaheads (Javascript, PCRE, Ruby, Java, Python) can use them to test whether the line/string contains these values, in any order:

```
^(?=.*\b(item1)\b)(?=.*\b(item2)\b)(?=.*\b(item3)\b)
```

For your [1.] data, this becomes:

```
^(?=.*\b(apple)\b)(?=.*\b(orange)\b)(?=.*\b(plum)\b)
```

You can see this on [regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/oV7wJ4/2).

For your [2.] data, this becomes:

```
^(?=.*\b(apple)\b)(?=.*\b(grape)\b)(?=.*\b(plum)\b)
```

You can see this on [regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/oV7wJ4/1).

You, of course, don't need to have the capture groups INSIDE of the lookaheads. You could simply match those items (without capture groups) and then use `.*` at the end of the pattern to match from the start of the line to the end:

```
^(?=.*\bapple\b)(?=.*\borange\b)(?=.*\bplum\b).*
```

Notice on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oV7wJ4/3) however that you no longer see results under MATCH INFORMATION (nothing was captured), but the entire line WAS selected as the match was valid.